# How to change gradelevels of all student at a time

Tags: php, mysql

I have a databases table 'stu_inf'o with columns 'stu_id (primary key)', 'name (varchar)' 'grade_id (foreign key)' and 'age (int)'.

The grade_level table has the following columns grade_level_id (primary key) and grade_level (varchar).

I have assigned a grade_id to all students. At the end of the year the grade_level will have to change to the next grade_id. Eg all 1 will have to change to 2 and all 2 to 3 and so on.

Changing these manually in the database will be time consuming and prone to errors like grade_id skipping and not moving some students at all.

How do I achieve this automatically using php and mysql.

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE stu_int SET grade_id = grade_id + 1 WHERE grade_id < x

(x is your maximum grade_level_id), this will allow you to update the table even if a student has reached the maximum grade level without causing a foreign key violation. You may also just delete the student who has reached the maximum grade level:

UPDATE stu_info SET grade_id = grade_id + 1

DELETE FROM stu_int WHERE grade_id = x

Comment: That was helpful. But what if I want the update at the end of the school year. I have start_date (varchar) and end_date (varchar). How do I write the php code such that when end_date is up the UPDATE stu_int SET grade_id = grade_id + 1 WHERE grade_id < x will be executed automatically. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

this will help you [cron job](http://www.thesitewizard.com/general/set-cron-job.shtml).

schedule it yearly or as you want